# Security Patch SUPEE-10975 - Possible issues?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, security, patches, supee-10975

Magento has released a new security patch for M1, and updates for M1 and M2.

What issues should I look out for when upgrading or applying this patch?

[SUPEE-10975](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10975)

> SUPEE-10975, Magento Commerce 1.14.4.0 and Open Source 1.9.4.0 contain multiple security enhancements that help close remote code execution (RCE), cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and other vulnerabilities.

[Magento 2.3.0, 2.2.7 and 2.1.16](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.2.7-and-2.1.16-security-update)

> Magento Commerce and Open Source 2.3.0, 2.2.7 and 2.1.16 contain multiple security enhancements that help close Remote Code Execution (RCE), Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and other vulnerabilities.

Comment: Let's keep it in one question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251317/supee-10975-potential-issues