# Backup fuction gone in admin after sucessful upgrade to 1.9.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, backup

After successful upgrade to Magento 1.9.4 - the system backup function in completely gone in back-end admin. Beats me?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: The backup function was officially removed: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251945/66951

Comment: LOL? Why??! It was very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, and it's working now.

Open `app/etc/modules/Mage_all` and set

```
<Mage_Backup><active>false</active>
```

to

```
<Mage_Backup><active>true</active>
```

then enable the backup module in `system->Configuration->Advanced->Mage_Backup` set to active.

Try it, good luck.

Comment: You should not enable it, they deactivated it because it is a major security risk. You will have to find another way to backup.