# 1.9.4 thumbnails not loaded correctly from .thumbs dir

Tags: wysiwyg, bug, media-images, magento-1.9.4

... or *"breaking already broken features - what is Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getCorrectFileName() for?"*

M1 has a bug that thumbnails used in CMS blocks/pages (insert image button) are not stored/loeaded correctly.

To fix this we have used solution from https://www.ctidigital.com/blog/fixing-magento-improving-performance-of-the-wysiwyg-editor/

Worked well for years but now I've seen 1.9.4 also broke this!

1.9.4 replaced

> Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::getFilesCollection()

```
$thumbUrl = $this->getThumbnailUrl($item->getFilename(), true);
```

with

```
$thumbUrl = $this->getThumbnailUrl(
    Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getCorrectFileName($item->getFilename()),
    true);
```

This passes the **complete image path** to `getCorrectFileName()` (instead of filename only) and replaces all backslashes with underscores leading to always failed checks in `getThumbnailUrl()` - so every thumb is generated new every time.

```
/**
 * Correct filename with special chars and spaces
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 * @return string
 */
static public function getCorrectFileName($fileName)
```

This turns `var/www/[...]/Some/Image.jpg` into `_var_www_[...]_Some_Image.jpg` ...

---

Do you have a better idea then this?

```
$thumbImg = Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getCorrectFileName($item->getBasename());
...
$thumbUrl = $this->getThumbnailUrl($path . DS . $thumbImg, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit, I want to do some advertising for OpenMage LTS ...

Fixed in: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/984

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial or full fix: https://github.com/obsergiu/magento-wysiwyg-thumbail-fix